# jenkins output format not common

Tags: jenkins

I have moved from one partition to another my jenkins repository, it works but for some reason, the output is not showing the correct format, bold font are not present. Could you suggest a solution please. I attach some pictures to ilustrate the issue. Thank you all for your kindness.

Kind Regards

[image: wrong output]

[image: good output]

Answer (score 0):

At the end, sync again the repository fixed the issue.
rsync is the best.

Kind Regards